# Changing Your MAC Address/Without Root Privileges

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, networking, mac-address

I want to change the mac address of my phone without making any android rooting.

Comment: Though unlikely to be done without root, you can find some MAC spoofers [in this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=104#group_390).

Comment: There are MAC spoofers, but all the ones I have seen require root. There is also an issue where the drivers tell the program "Yep I've changed the mac address to <whatever>" but the address isn't actually changed at all. This is an area of ongoing research. Check out Chainfire's google Plus, he is the creator of 'SuperSU' that we nearly all use on rooted devices, he has an app called 'PRYFI' just for this, but there are a lot of issues in this area. Apple are building it in at an OS level in iOS 8 apparently.

Comment: It should be noted that Pry-Fi is a MAC address _randomizer_, and manual spoofing is "a feature you need to enable separately". iOS 8 will include MAC randomizing, but not manual spoofing as far as I could tell from the little I've gleaned from what has been released.

Comment: @filoxo yeah I got all my terms muddles there! Too tired, I think the point is ok but the terminology is totally wrong!